# updating taggedValue on EA with sparx API does not save to eapx file

Tags: file

I would like to update a taggedValue from my EA model. The value seems to be set after using taggedValue.Set("NewValue"). Also, it looks like the database is temporarily updated. However, the "NewValue" is never written into the .eapx file.

Here is my example code:

Element element = repository.GetElementByGuid("{CD7E7E60-5086-4fc8-B3B6-FE69094B659B}");

```
    Collection<TaggedValue> taggedValues = element.GetTaggedValuesEx();
  for (TaggedValue taggedValue : taggedValues) {

        if (taggedValue.GetName().equals("isEncapsulated")) {

            String value = "NewValue";
            taggedValue.SetValue(value);
            taggedValues.Refresh();

        }

     repository.SaveAllDiagrams();
     repository.CloseFile();
```

The new value is of the correct type.
Using taggedValue.Update() would also not work...

It looks like an access issue in order to be able to write into the .eapx file, which I never did before.

Can anyone help?. Thank you.

Best regards,
César